# Handlebars not loading local css file

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm using handlebars version 4.4.3 in express js application for rendering html. I'm trying to load bootstrap css in style tag. While using cdn link it's working fine. But I want to load from local path. If I'm using local path its not loading. I don't know why it's not working. I tried so many ways to load local css file. But my bad luck nothing helped. Anyone please suggest me how to use local css file in handlebars. Below I mentioned my tried codes everything.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
```

These much things i tried in my **registration_print.html** file. And also in my **express.js** file i mentioned static path.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../assets/templates'));
app.use("/assets", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/../assets")));
```

Below is my folder structure. Please anyone help me to solve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hey there here is how i did solve this:

First of all i would recommend you, try using express-hanldebars its an module which is special build for express and handlebars interactions.

Basicly you need to use app.use on the hole folder

[image: My structure]

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var hbs = require('express-handlebars');
var handlebars = require('./helpers/handlebars.js')(hbs);

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
// Settings for Handlebars moved to ./helpers/handlebars.js
app.engine('hbs', handlebars.engine);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
```

And here is how i used them in the template.

layout.hbs

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/navigation.css">
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap">
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.18.0/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- JQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.18.0/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
<!-- Custom JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/custom-script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/navigation.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    {{{ body }}}
</body>
</html>
```

I hope i could give you a hint feel free to ask if anything is unclear

EDIT:
I would try this out, my guess is that express can't see the assets folder:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'..','assets'));
```

And then for your html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Fine but i want compiled html string in response not rendered output. While checking express-handlebars document I can't able to find the solution. Can you please suggest me how to use compiling instead of render?

Comment: I Edit my anwser, i dont have a solution for your question but as for the css files you should try the edit since this is i think node messes some of the path up

Comment: This one not working for me. But thanks for your suggestion. I want compiled result only here.